# Lazy load module receiving a Page Template

Tags: spartacus-storefront

Related with @spartacus-storefront

How I can do to lazyload a module depending the 'Template' i receive in the `GET '/pages'` request?

Example: Homepage

- `GET (anonymous user) '/pages' -> {... template: LandingPage1Template } ->` I want to load LandingPage1.module with my custom component overrides
- `GET (connected user) '/pages' -> {... template: LandingPage2Template } ->` I want to load **another** module with another custom layout/slots/components

I want to have a way to make a mapping between the Templates and the modules I have to load.

Comment: This is not related with Angular exactly, because with the same route I can get different templates to render in my Angular + Spartacus application. So depending the template I want to load a specific module

Answer (score 0):

I don't really sure that we can implement such logic with Spartacus core mechanisms without pain, but I think, handling it on the SAP Commerce Cloud side will be the best approach.

For example, you can hold two separate templates `LandingPage1Template` and `LandingPage2Template` for Home Page, your SAP Commerce Cloud system can validate user's status and sends to Spartacus application different page structure with slots and components to display.

On the Spartacus Angular application side you should add configuration for separate templates, for example:

```
export const layoutSlotsConfig: LayoutConfig = {
  layoutSlots: {
    header: {
      xs: {
        slots: ['Header']
      },
      sm: {
        slots: ['Header']
      },
      md: {
        slots: ['Header']
      },
      lg: {
        slots: ['Header']
      }
    },
    LandingPage1Template: {
      slots: [
        'Section1C',
        'Section1A'
      ]
    },
    LandingPage2Template: {
      slots: [
        'Section2C',
        'Section2A'
      ]
    },
    footer: {
      slots: ['Footer']
    }
  }
};
```

And then, you can simply implement separate UI styles, slots and components for above templates via Spartacus core mechanisms, in another words, you can implement separate UI and logic for Home Page, based on user's status and you don't need to manipulate with modules on the frontend application side.

The same approach will also work perfectly for another website pages.

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer. 
Sorry but that is not actually our problem, maybe I didn't explain well the situation.

Another example:
Overriding the `AddToCartComponent (cx-add-to-cart)` but we want 2 differents overrides in 2 differents pages (*Product-list-page, Product-detail-page*). 

So I create one module for each page and in each module I did an override of the same cx-component but with a diffferent custom component. So I want to lazy load the Product list page module if i'm in that page and do one override, and the other one in the other case.

Now is not possible

Comment: @sebastian-fernandez, hi! Honestly saying, even in this example I don't know another way to figure it out :) In my opinion - creating separate component with another typeCode will be the best way, but if it doesn't work for you - yes, you are fully right, Spartacus doesn't have any alternatives to implement it in different way.